# Find a DLL location generated from nuget.exe

Tags: c#, batch-file, nuget

When I run build.bat to generate one DLL, I have an issue.
The build.bat creates an .exe file (nuget.exe) and one empty folder (bin).
But I can't find where the DLL is because when I run nuget.exe it opens and closes the console window too quickly and I cannot see where the location of these DLLs,i want to include in my c# project:

```
using IO.Swagger.Api;
using IO.Swagger.Client;
using Model;
```

Please see the following [link](https://github.com/BitMEX/api-connectors/tree/master/clients/csharp).
I have already tried to find them in all of the hard drive, I do not find them.

@ Dan Field here is the BATCH file (build.bat)

```
    @echo off
SET CSCPATH=%SYSTEMROOT%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319


if not exist ".\nuget.exe" powershell -Command "(new-object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('https://nuget.org/nuget.exe', '.\nuget.exe')"
.\nuget.exe install src\IO.Swagger\packages.config -o packages

if not exist ".\bin" mkdir bin

copy packages\Newtonsoft.Json.8.0.3\lib\net45\Newtonsoft.Json.dll bin\Newtonsoft.Json.dll
copy packages\RestSharp.105.1.0\lib\net45\RestSharp.dll bin\RestSharp.dll

%CSCPATH%\csc /reference:bin\Newtonsoft.Json.dll;bin\RestSharp.dll /target:library /out:bin\IO.Swagger.dll /recurse:src\IO.Swagger\*.cs /doc:bin\IO.Swagger.xml
pause
```

Comment: What's in build.bat?  What do you mean it's creating nuget.exe?  Is it calling that?  What DLL are you looking for?  If it's a nuget file have you checked in the packages folder in the solution?

Comment: @ Dan Field, i put the batch file (build.bat)

Comment: i'm looking for:IO.Swagger.dll,    the DLL

Comment: `where /R somepath mydll.dll`